# Combine several locations with regex in nginx

Tags: nginx, joomla, directory

I dynamic number of Joomla installations in subfolders of the domain.

For example:

```
    http://site/joomla_1/
    http://site/joomla_2/
    http://site/joomla_3/
    ...
```

Currently I have the follwing config that works:

```
index index.php;

location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}

location /joomla_1/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /joomla_1/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location /joomla_2/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /joomla_2/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/joomla.sock;
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to combine joomla_N rules in one:

```
location ~ ^/(joomla_[^/]+)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

but server starts to return index.php as is (does not call the php-fpm).

It looks like the nginx stops the processing of the regex rules after the first match.

Is there any way to combine this rules with something like regex?

Answer (score 2):

Let's understand things:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

> To determine which location directive matches a particular query, the
>   literal strings are checked first. Literal strings match the beginning
>   portion of the query - the most specific match will be used.
>   Afterwards, regular expressions are checked in the order defined in
>   the configuration file. **The first regular expression to match the
>   query will stop the search**. If no regular expression matches are
>   found, the result from the literal string search is used.

So first regex stop searching!

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files

> Checks for the existence of files in order, and returns the first file
>   that is found. A trailing slash indicates a directory - $uri /. In the
>   event that no file is found, an internal redirect to the last
>   parameter is invoked. The last parameter is the fallback URI and
>   *must* exist, or else an internal error will be raised.

So the last parameter of the `try_files` is an internal url on which the chain is reinvoked if no static file is found.

So answer 1 works because the `.php$` regexp is matched only when the internal redirect is invoked on the url, instead `joomla_[^/]` is matching always also on the internal php url.

To understand better also this works on a shell:

```
ln -s joomla_1 site_1
ln -s joomla_2 site_2 ...
```

nginx:

```
location ~ ^/site_(\d+) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /joomla_$1/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/joomla.sock;
    ...
}
```

User urls:

```
http://yoursite.tld/site_1/....
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the .php location first, and then put this after:

```
location ~ ^/joomla_(\d+) {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /joomla_$1/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```